# Create date and time from separate strings

Tags: ruby

I have an Orientation model that looks like this:

```
  create_table "orientations", :force => true do |t|
    t.date     "class_date"
    t.text     "class_time"
    t.integer  "seats"
    t.boolean  "active",     :default => true
    t.datetime "created_at",                   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   :null => false
  end
```

I would like to take the `class_date` and `class_time` fields and concatenate them to create a single DateTime object that I can compare to the current date/time. I know I can parse the time by using the following:

```
1.9.3-p545 :022 > o.class_time
 => "9:30am" 
1.9.3-p545 :023 > Time.parse(o.class_time)
 => 2014-07-28 09:30:00 -0400
```

but I'm not sure how to combine that with the class date.

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.parse("#{o.class_date} #{o.class_time}")`?

Comment: Any reason you are not using the `datetime` type anyway in your table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine a date and a time like this:

```
date = '2014-07-09'
time = '9:30am'

DateTime.parse([ date, time ].join(' '))
# => Wed, 09 Jul 2014 09:30:00 +0000
```

I've got my local time-zone in Rails set to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

There is the similar class method `parse` for `Date` class:

```
pry(main)> Date.parse '2013-08-31'
=> #<Date: 2013-08-31 ((2456536j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Note such method exists in `DateTime` as well:

```
pry(main)> DateTime.parse '2013-08-31 9:30am'
=> #<DateTime: 2013-08-31T09:30:00+00:00 ((2456536j,34200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

You can learn more on date/time in Ruby in my article [Ruby for Admins: Date and Time](http://rubyforadmins.com/date-and-time)

Answer (score 0):

You nailed it @tadman. Just for posterity, here is the method and call...

In my view...

```
    <% if orientation.active? and Orientation.is_not_past(orientation) %>
      <li class="class-available"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;
      <%= link_to orientation.class_time, new_orientation_registration_path(orientation) %>
    <% else %>
      <li class="class-closed"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>&nbsp;<%= orientation.class_time
```

%>
            <% end %>

In my model...

```
  def self.is_not_past(orientation)
    date = orientation.class_date
    time = Time.parse(orientation.class_time)
    datetime = DateTime.parse([ date, time ].join(' '))
    datetime > Time.now
  end
```

Comment: Is this a comment to @tadman's answer, or are you submitting an answer? If it's a comment, then please use a comment, don't create an answer.